# How to display array in a single column in table using DataTables?

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, ajax, datatables-1.10

I am in a big mess, as I am working in a unorthodox way. I am using DataTables for searching and pagination. I have a table in which I am getting vendors details like name, email, address, country etc and the materials on which vendors deal with. I am getting these results using inner join of two tables. In my scenario A vendor can be deal with multiple materials like shown in screenshot.

Here is the screen shot of my table view :

[image: table view]

Now the problem is I want materials of each vendor in each td but in my case each material is showing in each td which obviously destroying my table design.

Here is my HTML and JavaScript:

```
<table id="employee-grid" class="display" width="100%">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>

                            <th>Email</th>
                            <th>Country</th>
                            <th>Region</th>
                            <th>Material</th>
                            <th></th>
                            <th></th>
                            <th></th>
                            <th></th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
            </table>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="js/jquery.js"</script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" >
            $(document).ready(function() {
                var dataTable = $('#employee-grid').DataTable( {
                    "processing": true,
                    "serverSide": true,
                    "ajax":{
                        url :"employee-grid-data.php",

                    }
                } );
            } );
        </script>
```

and here is my ajax file :

```
<?php
/* Database connection start */
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "phwdata";

$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname) or die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());

/* Database connection end */


// storing  request (ie, get/post) global array to a variable  
$requestData= $_REQUEST;
//print_r($_REQUEST); 

$columns = array( 
// datatable column index  => database column name
    0 =>'name', 
    1 => 'email',
    2=> 'country',
    3=> 'region',
    4=> 'material'
);

// getting total number records without any search
$sql = "SELECT *";
$sql.=" FROM bp";
$sql.=" INNER JOIN pdbp";
$sql.=" ON (bp.id=pdbp.bp_id)";
$query=mysqli_query($conn, $sql) ;
$totalData = mysqli_num_rows($query);
$totalFiltered = $totalData;  // when there is no search parameter then total number rows = total number filtered rows.



$query=mysqli_query($conn, $sql) ;
$totalFiltered = mysqli_num_rows($query); // when there is a search parameter then we have to modify total number filtered rows as per search result. 
$sql.=" ORDER BY ". $columns[$requestData['order'][0]['column']]."   ".$requestData['order'][0]['dir']."  LIMIT ".$requestData['start']." ,".$requestData['length']."   ";
/* $requestData['order'][0]['column'] contains colmun index, $requestData['order'][0]['dir'] contains order such as asc/desc  */    
$query=mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die("employee-grid-data.php: get employees");

$data = array();
while( $row=mysqli_fetch_array($query) ) {  // preparing an array

    $nestedData=array(); 

    $nestedData[] = $row["name"];
    $nestedData[] = $row["email"];
    $nestedData[] = $row["country"];
    $nestedData[] = $row["region"];

    $mat = $row['material_cod'];
    $material=explode(",",$mat);
    foreach($material as $materials){
        $sql2 = "SELECT material";
        $sql2.=" FROM product_material";
        $sql2.=" WHERE material_cod = '$material'";
        $query2=mysqli_query($conn, $sql2);

        while( $row=mysqli_fetch_array($query2)) { 

                $nestedData[] = $row['material'];

            }

        }   

    $data[] = $nestedData;
}
```

I also go through nested object in DataTables [nested object](https://datatables.net/examples/ajax/objects_subarrays.html), but I am unable to figure out the solution.

Comment: can you display the array result using `json_encode`?

Answer (score 0):

Finally I get the solution, I declare the array inside the foreach loop. declare array outside the loop fix my issue. :)